# 20.04 Filesystem error after suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, filesystem, ext4

Two days ago, I installed some upgrades as usual, finished what I was doing, and went to bed. The following morning, when I opened my laptop lid (resuming it from suspension), I couldn't type in my password for about 10 seconds (this usually happens for about 5 seconds after resuming, so not *that* weird for me), but then I opened the top right menu to check on my VPN, and the menu was about three times taller than usual, with some icons missing and everything weirdly spaced out. Every few seconds my mouse would glitch back to its starting position in the bottom right corner. Within about 15 seconds, the system crashed completely and I was left with a white text message as below:

```
[  108.787159] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): __ext4_find_entry:1531: inode #36715
60: comm gdm-session-wor: reading directory lblock 0
[  108.787417] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[  108.787424] EXT4-fs (dm-1): I/O error while writing superblock
```

This message remained on a black screen background until I force powered off the computer. Upon restarting, it worked fine! Then I suspended again, and the exact same thing happened. I tried the same process a few more times, and always the same result: a filesystem error after I suspended the laptop.

I had left my laptop in a hot car boot accidentally that morning, after which it was pretty warm, so I worried that might've been the problem, **but the system works fine until I suspend, no issues before that**, which doesn't make sense to me if it were physical damage. I tried suspending from a live USB, no issues. I presume that would mean it has something to do with the updates I installed two days ago then.

I've done a full `rsync` backup onto an external drive to save everything, and that finished this morning. I have very little experience with Linux filesystems and kernel errors in general, so as much help as possible would be appreciated! I
assume I should try to roll back the upgrades, but they were Linux header upgrades and Ubuntu desktop upgrades, so how should I do that safely if at all?

Please note that I use a LUKS-encrypted drive as set up in the Ubuntu installer, if that has any bearing on a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for anyone else who gets this problem, it ended up being the `5.4.0-45-generic` Linux headers and image. I downgraded to the `5.4.0-42-generic` headers and my system worked flawlessly.

I followed the excellent instructions in [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/downgrade-kernel-linux/) article to downgrade. One problem though was that upon removing the 45 kernel, `apt` installed `linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-45-generic` for some reason, which I then had to remove to delete the 45 kernel completely (otherwise I was presented with a broken OS in which I couldn't even scroll...). Also, I was slightly intimidated by the prospect of autoremoving `intel-microcode`, but this actually caused no damage to my system whatsoever.

As always, make sure you have a backup before embarking on any kind of kernel alteration. Hopefully this bug will be fixed soon and those with this issue will be able to upgrade to `linux-headers-5.4.0-45-generic` through the normal Ubuntu methods!

Comment: same problem on 22.04 LTS with other kernels